# Is it possible to call directly ajax function from controller in play frame work?

Tags: java, ajax, playframework

How to call Ajax function directly from application Java class that extends controller in Play frame work; is it possible or not?

Comment: Ajax is called by browser

Comment: If you want to push information from server to browser, you can use Websockets, it's well documented on Play Framework Java (see samples). But considering such a question, you should read the doc before.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)